# Keras: How to extract label from image name as integer

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN to predict the resolution of images. I have train/test data with the following naming convention:

`labelName_imgName.jpg`

where `labelName` is an integer representing the resolution of the image. I want to extract the labels as integers so that my neural network can have a single output as the predicted label. Any help would be appreciated.

Currently I have a CNN that outputs the single number, but I have to feed it into a 100 dense layer (since resolutions range from 1 to 100) and the performance is poor. I am trying to verify that this method of labeling might be producing poor results due to the dense layer.

Comment: I'm having trouble myself understanding how `labelName` which is 9 alphabetic characters tells me the resolution of an image. Normally you look at the header inside an image to find its resolution. Can you clarify what you mean please? Maybe an example?

Comment: How can the answer be a single number? The dpi in the x-direction may be different from the y-direction, surely? Else images wouldn't store both.